# Why id, id $USER is different?

Tags: sudo, docker

I added my account to `docker` group.

```sh
joont@joont-ubuntu:~$ sudo gpasswd -a joont docker
```

and I typed `id` to check my account was added.

```
joont@joont-ununtu:~$ id
uid=1000(joont) gid=1000(joont) groups=1000(joont),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)
```

As you see, it doesn't applied.
But when I typed `id $USER`, result was different.

```
joont@joont-ununtu:~$ id joont
uid=1000(joont) gid=1000(joont) groups=1000(joont),999(docker)
```

Why they're different?

And now I still can't run `docker command` without `sudo`.

```
joont@joont-ununtu:~$ docker container ls
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Comment: Did you remember to logout/login after adding a group?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]